# Getting search bar to work in web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a list of profiles with a search bar to allow people to search for a specific user however the search bar doesn't seem to be working and I am get profile usernames in one line as opposed to seeing one line for each user name.

This is what I have in my js:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.service('MentorFinder', function() {

  return {
    get: function() {

      var mentors = [
          document.getElementById('mentor_list')
      ]

      return mentors;
    }
  }
})

.controller('pageController', function($scope, MentorFinder) {

  var mentors = MentorFinder.get();

  $scope.data = {
    mentors: mentors,
    searchQuery: ''
  };

  $scope.findMentors = function() {
    var searchQuery = $scope.data.searchQuery.toLowerCase();

    var filteredMentors = [];

    for (i = 0; i < mentors.length; i++) {
      if ( mentors[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1 ) {
        filteredMentors.push(mentors[i])
      }
    }

    $scope.data.mentors = filteredMentors;
  }

  $scope.clearSearch = function() {
    $scope.data.searchQuery = '';
  }
})
```

and my html:

```
  <ion-list id="mentor_list">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="mentor in data.mentors">
        {% for user in mentors %}
        {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
        {% endfor %}
        </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer given I have made the following changes to my js

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.service('MentorFinder', function() {
    const ionItems = document.querySelectorAll('#mentor_list ion_item');
    const names = Array.from(ionItems).map(ii => ii.innerHTML);
})

.controller('pageController', function($scope, MentorFinder) {

  var mentors = MentorFinder.get();

  $scope.data = {
    mentors: mentors,
    searchQuery: ''
  };

  $scope.findMentors = function() {
    var searchQuery = $scope.data.searchQuery.toLowerCase();

    var filteredMentors = [];

    for (i = 0; i < mentors.length; i++) {
      if ( mentors[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1 ) {
        filteredMentors.push(mentors[i])
      }
    }

    $scope.data.mentors = filteredMentors;
  }

  $scope.clearSearch = function() {
    $scope.data.searchQuery = '';
  }
})
```

Right now I am getting the search bar but cannot seem to return any user name if I type in a value in the search bar. I am not seeing a list of the users in my list

Comment: What's the `mentor_list` HTMLElement?  And how are `<ion-list>` and `<ion-item>` styled?

Comment: @avejidah this is the stylesheet I used-> //code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.css

mentor_list is mentors that was a typo will edit question

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('mentor_list')` gives you back an HTMLElement, which you then wrap in an array.  If what you want is the names--the innerHTML of the `ion-list` elements--then you need to extract the names out of `#mentor_list ion-items`.

Here's a simplified version of how to do that, minus the filter.  (And FWIW, you can simplify your code a bit by using `Array#filter`.)

```js
const ionItems = document.querySelectorAll('#mentor_list ion-item');
const names = Array.from(ionItems).map(ii => ii.innerHTML);

console.log(names);
```

```html
<ion-list id="mentor_list">
  <ion-item>Mickey Mouse</ion-item>
  <ion-item>Donald Duck</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here's an example with AngularJS.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', [])

.service('MentorFinder', function() {

  return {
    get: function() {
      const ionItems = document.querySelectorAll('#mentor_list ion-item');

      return Array.from(ionItems).map(ii => ii.innerHTML);
    }
  }
})

.controller('pageController', function($scope, MentorFinder) {

  var mentors = MentorFinder.get();

  $scope.data = {
    mentors: mentors,
    searchQuery: ''
  };

  $scope.findMentors = function() {
    var searchQuery = $scope.data.searchQuery.toLowerCase();

    $scope.data.mentors = mentors
      .filter(mentor => mentor.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1);
  }

  $scope.clearSearch = function() {
    $scope.data.searchQuery = '';
  }
})
```

```html
<ion-list id="mentor_list">
  <ion-item>Mickey Mouse</ion-item>
  <ion-item>Donald Duck</ion-item>
</ion-list>

<div ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="pageController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.searchQuery">
  <br>
  <button ng-click="findMentors()">Find</button>
  <br>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="mentor in data.mentors">{{mentor}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>

<script data-require="angular.js@1.7.8" data-semver="1.7.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `names` is not split into firstName-lastName tuples in my example, so I changed the filter logic a bit.

Also notice that I have two lists of mentors.  In your code, it looks like you are doing some server-side rendering of the initial list.

```
    {% for user in mentors %}
    {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
    {% endfor %}
```

If you use the `ngRepeat` directive on your server-generated `ion-list`, then the the list is going to get wiped out as soon a digest cycle happens.  So, you have a chicken-and-egg scenario, and as such I've added two `<ion-list>` to help clarify.

Comment: Thanks, So should I replace return {get: function()... with this?

Comment: Yep, that should do the trick.  Also, as an aside, you might want to avoid using `get` as a function name since it's a keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can only see the search bar and none of the users in my list. I cannot get a user if I type a name in the search bar neither

Comment: You appear to have a chicken-and-egg scenario in your code.  It looks like you're rendering a list of users server side, but then you're wiping those users out client side in your AngularJS code.

Comment: Per your edit, your MentorMethod.get method should still be present, and it should return `names`.

Comment: I updated the answer such that the snippet I provided is included in your AngularJS code.  I also tried to clarify why the mentor_list might be getting wiped out.

Comment: @Emm If you're still having a hard time digesting the answer, let's move this to a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206097/discussion-between-emm-and-avejidah).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipes to filter your searchQuery ng-model.

```
`
<ion-list id="mentor_list">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="mentor in data.mentors | filter:searchQuery">
        {{ mentor.first_name }} {{ mentor.last_name }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
`
```

Comment: This is more of a comment and doesn't answer the question.